# Extend time of an Countdowntimer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Why is this Code not working ?

This code should extend the Countdowntimer to 10 sec (everytime when point is 20 , 40 , 60) etc.But when I start it and my score is by 20 it shows in a TextView a right value of time.But then it is gone in 1 sec and the Countdowntimer got the old value and continue.Someone a idea ?

```
int bonus_time = 1 , sec = 10000 , point == 0; 

points_timer =new CountDownTimer(sec,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
                    if ( point == (bonus_time * 20))
                    {
                       ++bonus_time;
                       millisUntilFinished += 10000;
                       sec += 10000;
                    }

        ++point;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
          bonus_time = 1;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a timer with the `sec` variable for its time, it does not magically connect the two so when the value of `sec` changes the timer's time changes, it just uses the value of `sec` once when you make the timer.

Same goes for changing `millisUntilFinished`, it's a parameter you got from a callback, by changing its value you are not doing anything.

The only way to change a timer's time is to create a new one. This is my suggestion:

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
CountDownTimer points_timer;
int bonus_time = 1 , sec = 10000 , point == 0; 

public void createTimer()
{
    points_timer =new CountDownTimer(sec,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            sec = millisUntilFinished;

            if ( point == (bonus_time * 20))
            {
                ++bonus_time;
                //millisUntilFinished += 10000;
                sec += 10000;
                createTimer();
            }

            ++point;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
            bonus_time = 1;
        }
    };
}
```

The creation of the timer is surrounded by a function, and that function is called each time the bonus is gained to recreate the timer with the new value of `sec`.

- You should also call that method once in place of your previous code, to initially create the timer.

Hope this works..

Comment: Wouldn't this leak the onTick callback, so now it gets called twice every second?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extend a CountDownTimer, no method in the class provides this.

Your attempt to add time to `sec` is useless, I even wonder how it can compile. Anyway, in Java integers are passed by value, so once you passed `1000`, you passed it and can't change that value.

The only alernative is to re-create a new timer and use it instead of the old one. Or recode everything, a timer of your own that you can extend.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
```

you do

```
millisUntilFinished += 10000;
```

you can not assign to primitive parameter and expect that it changes anything outside of that method (eg. scope of millisUntilFinished  is onTick method and nothing more)